# While loop reverse print using foreach in Apache Velocity

Tags: java, while-loop, velocity

I have a Tree like data structure using the following single class instance:

```
class Human {
  String name;
  Human parent;
  Human[] children;
}
```

If we consider a certain instance `A`, it has it's parent Human instance as well as an array of it's child instances.

```
ROOT
 |- A
 |  |-A1
 |  |  |-A1_1
 |  |  |-A1_2
 |  |-A2
 |    
 | 
 |- B
```

So I get a certain leaf node (ex:`A1_2`), and I want to print all it's parents from the Root node.

ex:

```
ROOT > A > A2
```

We can do the same in Java by using a while loop until `parent!=null`. (But it will print it in reverse order , so need some extra effort to reverse it back)

My question is,

- How can I use foreach in velocity to achieve this?
- Is Keeping the list of ancestor , the best way to do this?

**EDIT**

If I add a new field to keep ancestors, I can set it as bellow, and can print it any direction:

```
class Human {
  String name;
  Human parent;
  Human[] children;
  Human[] ancestors;

  // getters and setters 
}
```

.

```
public static void printTree(Human h){
    List<Human> ancestors = new ArrayList<Human>();
    Human parent = h.getParent();
    while (parent!=null) {
        ancestors.add(parent);
        parent = parent.getParent();
    }
    h.setAncestors(ancestors.toArray(new Human[ancestors.size()]));
    printUsingVelocity(h);
}
```

Comment: how you are currently printing other elements in velocity, can you provide details about what you have tried so far.

Comment: I was only able to try this 'while loop' in Java, not yet have any idea about how the template should be.

Comment: You have almost answered part the question yourself by putting some options. These are the two approaches I have used in different situations. You can choose the one which gives you better readability.